# Plot in shiny appears different in browser

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I tried to write a simple application in shiny. Below is the ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Explore mtcars dataset"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("inputDF","Enter Y to plot vs mpg",choices = c('wt','disp','hp'))
    ),
    plotOutput("plot1")
  )
))
```

Below is the server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    g <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y=input$inputDF, col=factor(cyl)))
    g + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm")
  })
})
```

When I just run the ggplot separately, the plot appears perfect as I it is supposed to be.

[image: Standalone image]

But, it appears like a straight line running in `Run App`. What is wrong in this? I have attached the plot.

[image: Output_screenshot]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest way is to use `aes_string` instead of `aes`to process string input from `input$inputDF`:

```
g <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes_string(x='mpg', y=input$inputDF, col='factor(cyl)'))
```

You can also use [quasinotation / tidy evaluation](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/07/ggplot2-tidy-evaluation/) :

```
library(rlang)
g <- ggplot(data=mtcars, aes(x=mpg, y= !! sym(input$inputDF), col=factor(cyl)))
```

[image]